# Calling every possible combination of functions

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, computer-science, combinatorics

Say I have a bunch of functions, each labelled doThing1, doThing2 etc up to doThing10. I want to call every possible combination of these functions. Each function does not have to be called however each function can only be called once. How could I implement this in efficient manner in python?

Comment: What do you mean by "every possible combination?" Give us an example with, say, three functions. Also, do you really mean *combination*? Or did you mean *permutation*?

Comment: I mean combination, the order does not matter. A possible combinations is doThing1,doThing3,doThing2 however another possible combination doThing1,doThing2 or just doThing1 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.permutations(iterable\[, r\])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to get all the permutations and put your functions in a list.

Here is an example:

```
import itertools

def doThing1():
    print "thing 1"

def doThing2():
    print "thing 2"

def doThing3():
    print "thing 3"

functions = [doThing1, doThing2, doThing3]

for func_list in itertools.permutations(functions):
    for func in func_list:
        func()
```

Here is the output of that:

```
$ python permutations.py 
thing 1
thing 2
thing 3
thing 1
thing 3
thing 2
thing 2
thing 1
thing 3
thing 2
thing 3
thing 1
thing 3
thing 1
thing 2
thing 3
thing 2
thing 1
```

Comment: OP asked for combinations, not permutations. Also, he said that not every function has to be called every time, so presumably the combination of `thing1, thing3` is valid. You'll need to do 1-function combinations, 2-function combinations, and 3-function combinations.